# Indefinite integral of f(ax + b)

Tags: calculus

I was studying Calculus and I ran into this following expression:

$$\eqalign{\int f(ax + b)dx =\dfrac{1}{a}F(ax+b)}$$

I was wondering what it means, I couldn't figure out though. Also, what is the name of this theorem? So I can look up on the internet its proof and its usage

Thanks in advance

Comment: Usually in this context $F$ denotes the integral function of $f$ ( a primitive function of $f$ ). For example, $\int \cos (ax+b) dx = \frac{1}{a} \sin (ax+b) + C$

Comment: Thanks, @Crostul! So, can you walk me through its proof?

Answer (score 3):

Substitute $y = ax + b$. Then $dy = adx$, so 
$$\int f(ax + b) \ dx = \int f(y) \ \frac{dy}{a} = \frac{1}{a}\int f(y) dy.$$

$F(x)$ commonly denotes the antiderivative of $f$. That is, $F'(x) = f(x)$ and $\int f(x) \ dx = F(x) + c$.

Put these two statements together and you're there. It's too straightforward a result to deserve a name, I would just call it a simple case of integration by substitution.

Comment: thanks for your reply. So I may not call it the U-Substitution technique? Because I was searching on the internet and it was the closest I got to what I was looking for

Comment: Also, in which context I would use this? when trying to integrate a function that was differentiated using the chain rule?

Comment: Yes, it's common to use $u$ as your substitution variable, but it's completely arbitrary, I used $y$ (it's a dummy variable that doesn't exist outside the integrand).

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's sort of a reverse to the chain rule, just as integration by parts derives from the Leibniz product rule. Those are in some philosophical sense the only two techniques for integration (everything else is a trick of sorts).

Comment: thanks a lot for your time and answer!